# Ошибка при компиляции в XCode

Tags: xcode

Хочу выложить новую версию приложения. При компиляции появляется сообщение —

> The parent bundle has the same identifier (com.company.Appname) as sub-bundle at /Users/path/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/46DA430A-AA10-42CF-B9FD-58F272FB67E5/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.UVHWQJ/extracted/Appname.app/PlugIns/

Не могу понять: что не так и как исправить.

Comment: Что предшествовало этому?

Comment: Особо ничего, это стикеры - добавил три картинки, поменял номер билда и версию. Далее пытаюсь скомпилировать - получаю ошибку.